# How to find all the matching substrings in a particular line?

Tags: python, regex

I have several lines of text listing several instructions of a processor. I need to look for all the patterns of the form `<x; y, z>`. There could be two or more such patterns in each line. I want all the patterns in each set (the three digits within <> ) to be copied into a single list for further analysis.

I have tried using `entries = re.findall("<[0-9]; [0-9], [0-9]>", line)`.

I want the output to look like this for each line:

Output

```
[x, y, z, a, b, c] # (where all the entries are integer values)
```

However, this is not sufficient, what is the best way to implement what I want?

Comment: Please provide an example for input and expected output. It's not clear how 3 digits turn into 6

Comment: I think you might have to do a re.findall, along with maybe some split and trim commands, unless you want to do multiple regex commands, and then convert to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Say line is like
`line='<7;8,9><8;7,4><7;a,z>'`

`[x for x in re.split(r'[<;,>]',line) if re.search('[0-9]',x) or re.search('[a-z]',x)]`
`Out[347]: ['7', '8', '9', '8', '7', '4', '7', 'a', 'z']`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit clumsy, but it should get you what you need.

```
items = re.findall("<[0-9]+; [0-9]+, [0-9]+>", line)
out = []
for item in items:
    separated = item.split(';')
    out.append([int(separated[0].strip()), int(separated.split(',')[0].strip()), int(separated.split(',')[1].strip())])
```

Basically, after you find all the items you need using findall, we are separating the numbers out using split and strip, and converting them to integers at the same time.  `out` should be a list of lists, where each item will contain the numbers in order.

Notice that I used the spacing that you seem to have in your code.  If there are no spaces, then the `strip()` commands are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text  = ["<92; 29,17><99; 8,3>","no match here","<2; 9,1><999;18,3>"]

lines = []    # all the line results 

for line in text:  # go over each line

    oneLine = []       # matches for one line 

    for m in re.findall("<(\d+); ?(\d+),(\d+)>", line):  # find all patterns
        oneLine.extend(map(int,m))                       # convert to int, extend oneLine

    if oneLine:                                          # add to lines if not empty
        lines.append(oneLine) 

print (lines)
```

Output:

```
[[92, 29, 17, 99, 8, 3], [2, 9, 1, 999, 18, 3]] # each inner list is 1 line
```

I modified the pattern, it looks for

```
<     - literal character
\d+   - 1 to n numbers
;     - literal character
space - optional space
\d+   - 1 to n numbers
,     - literal ,
\d+   - 1 to n numbers
>     - literal >
```